# Putting WD Datacenter drives in a NAS

Tags: windows-server-2008, datacenter, small-business

I want to put a RAID10 array of 4x5TB WD Datacenter drives in a server. What happens if I don't want to use the server anymore and I want to use those drives in a NAS instead? Does it have to be a NAS drive like the WD Red?

I think there is an obvious answer to this question, but I just want to make sure the drives I buy will be usable in another setup. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Comment: On a more serious note, since your question is very unclear and sparse on details,  it is unlikely that you can preserve the data on the disks unless both the server and NAS appliance use the same model of RAID controller.

Comment: Regarding your edit: **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com. - Server and NAS drives are designed/engineered for different workloads and environments and may contain different firmware especially compared to desktop disks. That may not be a problem at all, or it might manifest in a bit shorter lifecycle, which you can mitigate with adequate monitoring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they are compatible, they should work just fine. What's the concern here? Are you worried about something you aren't saying?

You know NAS is just a generic term for a storage server that resides on a network right?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage